# How to make a serialization with recursive traversal?

Tags: c#, serialization, recursion, traversal, tree-traversal

My serializer serializes  properties and fields.
If there will be a custom complex type, my serializer won't work.
I would like to add a serialization of custom complex types and allow possibility of doing recursive traversal. 
I'm new to programming and frankly I never had deal with recursive traversal.

This is what I have now:

```
internal class MySerializer
{
    private Type targetType;

    public MySerializer(Type targetType)
    {
        this.targetType = targetType;
        if (!targetType.IsDefined(typeof (DataContractAttribute), false))
            throw new Exception("No soup for you");
    }

    public void WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
    {
        IEnumerable<MemberInfo> serializbleMembers =
            targetType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance |
                                  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof (DataMemberAttribute), false));
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine("<" + targetType.Name + ">");
        foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in serializbleMembers)
        {
            writer.Write("\t<" + memberInfo.Name + ">");
            var fieldInfo = memberInfo as FieldInfo;
            if (fieldInfo != null)
            {
                writer.Write(fieldInfo.GetValue(graph).ToString());
            }

            var propInfo = memberInfo as PropertyInfo;
            if (propInfo != null)
            {
                writer.Write(propInfo.GetValue(graph, null).ToString());
            }

            writer.Write("</" + memberInfo.Name + ">");
        }
        writer.WriteLine("</" + targetType.Name + ">");
        writer.Flush();
    }
}


[DataContract]
class Person 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string _family;
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }      
 }
```

Comment: So as far as I understand your question, you want to write your own serializer, correct? Can you explain more which requirement forces you to do so? There are maybe some other possibilities to achieve what you need...

Comment: Yes, you understood correct. I'm writing it because I'm curious. At first I wanted to create a my own simple serializer. Now I want to serialize a custom complex types and add recursive traversal, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're looking for is a [post-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_2) of the object, where you can hit all of the leaves first, and return the serialization up to the parent object.  If you go this route though I would recommend using the iterative approach rather than the recursive, since traversing a very complex object could result in a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_deep_recursion).

The problem with this approach is that it only works if the objects being serialized are trees.  Many times they are, but many object hierarchies are actually directed graphs.  You could easily have two complex objects that point to each other, in which case you would just be infinitely traversing.